# #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am learning the Lisp programming language. I have written a simple program:

```
(defun abs(x)
  (cond ((> x 0) x)
        ((= x 0) 0)
        ((< x 0) (- x))))

(print (abs 5))
```

when I compile and run this code, i get the following warning:

```
WARNING: DEFUN/DEFMACRO(ABS): #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked
         Ignore the lock and proceed
WARNING: DEFUN/DEFMACRO: redefining function ABS in /home/lisp/file.lisp, was defined in C
```

I didn't understand why is this warning given, what does it mean?
can anybody explain it?

Comment: In addition to FrédéricHamidi's comment, note that there's already an [**abs**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_abs.htm)  function defined in Common Lisp.  You can't redefine it.  Either use a different package, or a different name (e.g., **my-abs**).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to redefine an ANSI Common Lisp function
[`abs`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_abs.htm)
and the system is warning you about it.

Please see ["package locking"](http://clisp.org/impnotes/pack-lock.html)
in the manual.

(You now owe me [1 zorkmid](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine)).